Polyline to polygon
When trying to do polygons from polylines I always fail and end up using my old program ArcView3.2 and Xtools.
It is probably something I do wrong but I cant see what it is. The below is the result of this zipfile 
Is there someone that has a step by step instruction, that include what to do to correct the polyline-file

You have geometry errors: the points are not in a logical order. When I extract the vertices from the line you provide and label them with @id, see e.g. the upper left part of your line (even in your screenshot, the green cross indiecates a line crossing). You have vertex 41/42 on the same place somewhere in the middle of your shape, but vertex 44 is on the upper left. So the order of your lines is quite messy and you should clean up it first before creating polygons.
EDIT
An easy was to solve the proble (tested with your data): use Polygonize instead of Lines to polygon, then it works, see last screenshot below.


Red: correct polygon with Polygonize; yellow: wrong polygon with lines to polygons:


how do I change the order?

This is not so easy, apart from doing it manually. An option would be trying to apply a small buffer on your polygons, dissolve the result and apply a negative buffer with the same value.

thanks for the tip

Looks like Spatialite's Polygonize can get the job done.
You have one line with NULL geometry, select the rest, st_union (=dissolve) them and polygonize:
SELECT polygonize(geometry) AS geometry
FROM
(SELECT st_union(geometry) AS geometry
FROM tv
WHERE geometry IS NOT NULL) AS dissolved


Then you can right-click the layer and export to file.
